# MATLAB zoom on all images on a GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have a GUI that show 4 images. I turn the zoom on but I can only click on an image and zoom one image at a time. Is there a way to implement the code so that when I zoom on an image, the other 3 images will also zoom to the same level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to link all the axes together using [`linkaxes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html?refresh=true) which will cause them all to zoom and pan at the same time in the same way.

```
load mri;
img = D(:,:,12);

figure();

ax1 = subplot(1,2,1);
imagesc(img, 'Parent', ax1);
axis(ax1, 'image');

ax2 = subplot(1,2,2);
imagesc(img, 'Parent', ax2);
axis(ax2, 'image');

linkaxes([ax1, ax2]);

colormap gray;
```

[image]

> **NOTE** This force the x and/or y limits to be the same. This obviously requires all of your images to be the same size. If they are not, you can modify the XData and YData of each image to make them the same scale.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I'm looking for.